# Scraping HTML in R Using xpathSapply - Not Returning All Rows

Tags: html, r

Thanks in advance for helping.

Using R, I am attempting to scrape 2016 presidential voting results at the county level from Politico's site - http://www.politico.com/2016-election/results/map/president/ohio/ (I put in Ohio at the end of the URL b/c that's my test case).

To do so, I am using two methods from R's XML library - first htmlTreeParse and then xpathSApply.

I have targeted the elements that I want to capture, but it only returns 11 results - those of the overall result for the state and the first 10 counties.  The problem is that there are 88 counties in Ohio:

[image]

After inspecting the html to identify differences after the 11th row, the only thing that I could identify was an extra tag every 10 rows (makes sense considering my results) named 'data-z = "10", 'data-z = "20", etc:

[image]

My code is listed below - you should be able to plug and run:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

county_election_url <- "http://www.politico.com/2016-election/results/map/president/ohio"
county_parse <- htmlTreeParse(county_election_url, useInternalNodes = T)

xpathSApply(county_parse, "//div[@id = 'globalWrapper']//div[@class = 'super-duper']//article[@class = 'results-group']//table[@class = 'results-table']//tr[@class = 'type-republican']//td[@class = 'results-percentage']//span[@class = 'percentage-combo']//span[@class = 'number']",xmlValue)
```

Can this problem be solved using the XML library?  Or does a rocket ship need to be built?

Comment: hrbmstr, is it necessary for the solution to be a rocket ship?  Is there any way using the XML library w/html functions to address this problem?